# Dual use of keys in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to assign the number 1 so that when I press it the result is to send to the computer qx and then enter.

```
1:: Send, qx{ENTER}
q:: Send, jx{Enter}
```

But then I also want to assign the letter q to send something else to the computer. Is it possible to do this? I'm concerned that if I assigned 1 to something that involves q, then whenever I press 1 q will also be called, and we'll end up in a loop.

Is there some way to fix it so AHK 'knows' when qx gets sent that I don't want to call the q function (and hence jx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thinking. The AutoHotKey developers have thought about that and introduced the $ to prevent this "loop"

example:

```
$1::Send, q
$q::Send, 1
```

Pressing 1 will generate a q, but due to the $ it will NOT trigger the second hotkey and vise versa.

So by pacing a $ in front of the q, you will prevent this loop in your situation.

Comment: or to prevent that on all hotkeys, put [`#InstallKeybdHook`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) at the top of your file.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, Thanks for completing the answer.